# How to use multiset in C++?

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl, multiset

Why is my code giving a compilation error?

I want to have a multiset that can contain 3 items in a sorted order of the first item, if there is a tie then the second item, if there is again a tie then the third item.

Please suggest me a solution or any other data structure.

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n ; 
    multiset<int, pair<int, int>> m;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < n ;i++)
    {
        int a, b, c ;
        cin >> a >> b >> c; 
        pair<int, int> p1 = make_pair(b, c) ;  
        pair<int, pair<int, int>> p2 = make_pair(a, p1) ; 
        m.insert(p2)  ; 
    }

    for(auto it = m.begin() ; it != m.end() ;it++)
    {
        cout << it->first << " " << it->second.first << " " << it->second.second << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: `multiset<int,pair<int,int>> m ;` is not valid for a set,  did you mean to use `std::multimap` ?

Comment: Change `multiset<int, pair<int, int>> m;` to `multiset<pair<int, pair<int, int>>> m;`.  And consider `std::tuple<int, int, int>` as a bit more friendly.

Comment: can you suggest me a data structure which takes a  list of 3 members in a sorted way in order of  1st member , if there is tie the 2nd member and if again there's a tie then 3rd member . and at the same time i want to perform actions like erase and insert in approx O(logn) time . and thanks for the answers

Comment: Maybe `std::multiset<std::tuple<int, int, int>>`?

Comment: That would be [`std::multimap<>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap)

Comment: Obligatory link to [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Answer (score 2):

> Why is my code giving a compilation error?

You are getting a compilation error is because `multiset` only accept a single template for data type. The second template parameter is for a comparison function, which `pair<int, int>` is definitely not one.

> I want to have a multiset which can contain 3 items and in a sorted order of first item, if there is a tie then second item, if there is again tie then third item.

What you are looking for is `std::multiset<std::tuple<int, int, int>>`.

Just like `pair`, `tuple` would compare the first data, and if the first data ties, it goes to the second data, and so on. In fact, `pair` is a specific case of `tuple` with only 2 elements.

Do note that to access data in a `tuple`, you can't use <del>`tuple.first`</del> or <del>`tuple.second`</del>, instead you have to use `std::get<INDEX>(your_tuple)`. Also since `INDEX` here is a compile time variable, so you can not use a for loop to access elements of a `tuple` like an array.